# Samba share distributed on VPN subnet

Tags: networking, server, samba, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to connect to a Samba share through a VPN I set up using OpenVPN.
Both, Samba and OpenVPN are set up within a Virtual Machine runnning Ubunutu 14.04.
On the client side I'm using several windows machines. The VPN is just working fine, I am currently routing web-traffic from the clients to the www (kind of a web-proxy) and I am able to reach other clients as well as the serving machine itself (ping and websites).
current subnets I use:

- I'm not sure if you can say there is a "subnet" on the server side as it is a Virtual Machine which has it's own VLAN
- client subnet is 172.16.0.0/16
- VPN subnet is 192.168.0.0/24

`ifconfig` output on the server is (blacked out the public ip):

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:1100 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1100 (1.1 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:192.168.0.1  P-t-P:192.168.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6046 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7621 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
      RX bytes:549492 (549.4 KB)  TX bytes:6177350 (6.1 MB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
      inet6 addr: ::2/128 Scope:Compat
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:77095 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:84984 errors:0 dropped:32 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:26204249 (26.2 MB)  TX bytes:25862190 (25.8 MB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  P-t-P:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Using a different subnet for the VPN (10.8.0.0./24), to avoid collision in case I have overseen something... didn't work anyway.

The **OpenVPN server.conf** I use looks like this:

```
port 1095

proto tcp

dev tun0

ca /usr/share/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /usr/share/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /usr/share/easy-rsa/keys/server.key

dh /usr/share/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem

server 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

;push "route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0"

push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option WINS 208.67.220.220"

client-to-client

keepalive 10 120

auth SHA1

cipher BF-CBC

comp-lzo

user <sambauser>
group <sambagroupshare>

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log
log-append  openvpn.log

verb 3
```

the `<sambauser>` is the user who owns the directory I want to access and is also a member of the group `<sambashare>` which owns the directory.
Tried different users and groups here, too.

**Maybe there is anything I have to take care of regarding user rights management?**

I also enabled `push "route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0"`, disabled it because I don't get the use of it anyway.

`testparm` shows the following about the **smb.conf**:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Processing section "[homes]"
Processing section "[share]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
    workgroup = LAB
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    interfaces = tun0
    bind interfaces only = Yes
    server role = standalone server
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    unix password sync = Yes
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    dns proxy = No
    wins support = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/24


[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    create mask = 0740
    directory mask = 0740
    directory mode = 0740


[share]
    comment = share
    path = /home/share
    create mask = 0600
    directory mask = 0740
    directory mode = 0740
    guest ok = Yes
```

Further I have set `hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/24`

The rules I use for **iptables** looks like this:

```
#
# NAT
#

*nat

# Route all VPN Subnet traffic to the www
-A POSTROUTING -o venet0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
#-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source 81.169.250.110
#-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source $(ifconfig venet0:0 | grep -i 'inet' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')

COMMIT

#
# FILTER
#

*filter

#
# FILTER - INPUT
#

# Log incoming traffic
#-A INPUT -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables: " --log-level 7
#-A INPUT -p udp -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables: " --log-level 7

# Allows all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that does not use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT

# Accepts all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# HTTP
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# HTTPS
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# VPN
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1095 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# SAMBA
-A INPUT -i tun0 -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT

# Allows SSH connections
# The --dport number *has to be* the same as in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -m limit --limit 1/m --limit-burst 5 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ping
#  note that blocking other types of icmp packets is considered a bad idea by some
#  remove -m icmp --icmp-type 8 from this line to allow all kinds of icmp:
#  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22711
#-A INPUT -s 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
# Allow all kinds of icmp
-A INPUT -i tun0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# log iptables denied calls (access via "dmesg" command)
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

# Drop everything else
-A INPUT -j DROP

#
# FILTER - FORWARD
#

# Forward all established connections
-A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# VPN - PROXY
-A FORWARD -o venet0 -i tun0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

# Drop everything else
-A FORWARD -j DROP

#
# FILTER - OUTPUT
#

# Accepts all established outbound connections
-A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTP and HTTPS
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT

# VPN
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1095 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1095 -j ACCEPT

# SAMBA
#-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 137 -j ACCEPT

#-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 138 -j ACCEPT

#-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 139 -j ACCEPT

#-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 445 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ping
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Drop everything else
-A OUTPUT -j DROP

#
# /FILTER
#

COMMIT
```

I don't know, what else I can do about this. I tried several iptables configuration, like allowing all *INPUT* coming from *tun0*: `-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT`.

Also I tried disabling the `hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/24`-line and disabled binding to the *tun0*-interface. On the other side I tried tightening the interface binding like this:

```
hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/24
interfaces = 192.168.0.0/24 tun0
bind interfaces only = yes
```

which of course didn't make any notable difference.

Trying to reach the share from Windows manually by typing `\\192.168.0.1\share` or `\\192.168.0.1` into the address line of the Windows explorer ends by prompting an error message.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me and I welcome any suggestions!

Kind regards
g.a

Comment: It's good with lots of relevant information, but it's not very clear what you are asking. Are you asking how to connect to a samba server on a VPN network configured like above, from a Windows client? If so, can the Windows client connect to the server running samba on the same interface as samba runs on at all? For example, can the Windows client ping the samba server?

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for your response! :)
Yes, I want to connect to the samba-server on a VPN network configured like above from a windows-client. I can ping the server using the VPN subnet IP. Also I can connect to the remote server, which runs samba, using it as a proxy.

Comment: Are you connecting to smb server to 192.168.0.0 or 192.168.0.1? If you are connecting to 192.168.0.0 then try 192.168.1.1. For testing purposes enable all hosts in the smb.conf.

Comment: Hi, @kukulo!thanks for your response.Recently I've set back the VPN subnet to 10.8.0.0/24. the server gets 10.8.0.1 this is what I usually connect to. Trying to connect to the share manually via \\10.8.0.1 and \\10.8.1.1 isn't working either. Connecting to 10.8.0.1 at least gives me an error prompt saying: "The remote device or resource won't accept the connection". Also tried enabling the "hosts allow = ALL" option, that did not make any changes.

Comment: I searched through the samba logfiles and noticed the following error after trying to connect to the samba-share:
`[2016/04/19 10:23:51.889912,  0] ../source3/smbd/process.c:263(read_packet_remainder)
  read_fd_with_timeout failed for client 10.8.0.6 read error = NT_STATUS_END_OF_FILE.`

Related to this, I found out it could be an issue with IPv6, which I disabled via iptables.

Comment: Can you connect to the smb from the local subnet - without vpn?

Comment: Windows shares use Netbios to resolve names , this is a layer-2 broadcast based name discovery protocol. Layer-2 broadcasts do not traverse layer-3 boundaries such as  VPNs.  You will need to use WINS to do this which you have enabled so it would suggest your WINS  settings are not correct or add host file entries on the clients so they can resolve the addresses correctly.

Comment: @ kukulo there is no way to get into the local subnet, because it's a virtual server I rented.

Answer (score 1):

I see in your smb.conf that you are trying to combine tun interface with "bind interfaces only" configuration directive. Since tun is not "broadcast-capable" interface, this will not work (see Samba doc for the "bind interfaces only").
192.168.0.0/24 in your later config is still the same tun interface and as such this change could not help.

As a result Samba is not listening anywehre and therefore is not able to serve any requests.

You can check whather this is the case in log.smbd with log level = 3. You will probably find something like:

[YYYY/MM/DD HH:HH:SS.ssssss,  X] ../source3/lib/interface.c:316(add_interface)
  not adding **non-broadcast interface tun0**

[YYYY/MM/DD HH:HH:SS.ssssss,  X] ../source3/lib/interface.c:543(load_interfaces)
  WARNING: **no network interfaces** found

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access samba only through VPN then Global section in smb.conf should have these lines:

```
   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/24
   hosts deny = ALL
   hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.1/24
```

Comment: Hi @Taavi thanks for your response.
I changed my current smb.config considered  to your suggestions, except I substituted the `192.168.0.0/24` subnet with `10.8.0.0/24`.
But I still get the same errors.

Comment: Isn't your VPNs subnet 192.168.0.0/24? 
_The OpenVPN server.conf I use looks like this:
server 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0_

Comment: A sorry, read your post again. I don't think _bind interfaces only_ = _Yes_ option is necesary if you use _hosts deny_ and _hosts allow_. Try removing this one. Also as you have made many changes please post the latest Samba config.